# In R Studio editor, how to delete the previous word along with the whitespace after it?

Tags: r, editor, rstudio, whitespace, removing-whitespace

It seems really strange to me that in R Studio, unlike in virtually every other editor, when I press `Option + Delete` on Mac, only the whitespace is deleted, but not the word before the whitespace. This seems totally counterintuitive and gets annoying really quickly.

For example:

For `word1 .`, if I place the cursor before the `.`, I'd expect `Option + Delete` to delete both the whitespace and `word`, resulting in `.` However, I get `word1.` instead.

Is there any configuration I got wrong and should change to fix the behavior, or is it just the intended behavior of R Studio? If so, is there an alternative way to delete the previous word directly? (using Vim key binding works but I'd like a vanilla solution.)

Comment: I notice the same behavior (deleting only whitespace before a word) in Notepad++ on Windows... In Word, a word gets deleted as well, but who uses Word anyway, ey?

Comment: have you tried `command + delete`? don't. deletes the whole line.

Comment: What editors are you using for reference? I see the same behavior in Sublime, VSCode, TextMate; I see the whitespace deletion in e.g. TextEdit, so the behavior you describe is definitely not universal.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because if the functionality isn't there you should request it from the RStudio company themselves. Submit a feature request.